# VSTS: Release and deploy a console application

Tags: visual-studio, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a C# .NET project using Visual Studio 2013 and we're setting it up to release and deploy with Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS). The websites were pretty simple and easy to set up and they work fine. A few projects are libraries or Console applications and we're trying to determine the best method for creating an automated release for these.

The publish profile asks for a location to publish to - we've experimented with the build drop on our VSTS build server (where all of the other files are) and then asks for a website, a UNC path or a CDROM. We chose "UNC Path" and put the same build drop location in, but in UNC format.

It hasn't really worked yet, so I thought I would see if any best practices for creating VSTS releases and deploys for Console or Code Libraries exist.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered installing the agent on the target environments and using a release definition that simply copies the right files at the right place?
Regards

Note: copy path shouldn't be hardcoded and rely on variables.

To specify the agent queue by going to the tasks tab when editing the release definition. Click on the "run on agent" header, that will open the details, select your queue here.
[image]

Agent queues can contain multiple agents, so your job when you add agents is to organize them by queues that make sense in your context.

Comment: How can you specify the agent for the release?

Comment: updated the answer to add those details, don't forget to upvote :)